# Clearing Meteor.userId() from client browser after calling Meteor.logoutOtherClients()?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-accounts, meteor-useraccounts

When I open up a browser #1 and log in to our app and then open browser #2 and log in to our app, the first browser log in session closes. I am accomplishing this by calling `Meteor.logoutOtherClients()`.

However, I notice that in browser #1, the `Meteor.userId()` still exists with an id even after logout from server side. How can I clear this?   I no longer would like an id to exist in browser #1

Comment: This should not happen. How do you know that #1 browser session is closed?

Comment: logoutOtherClients logs out all but the current/new login

Comment: Meteor.logoutOtherClients() will log you out from server. in client side  you should use guards or resolves for component access. for login use Meteor.user() in place of Meteor.userId(). Meteor.userId() check in localstorage but Meteor.user() you will get from server side. hope this help :)

Comment: @Amitkumar, both Meteor.user() and Meteor.userId() continue to resolve :-(

Comment: They do resolve and the scary part is the token still lives... this should be considered a security related issue imho. We've moved our app away from Meteor since I asked this question.